# The text change shown in the revision page is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

I edited an answer to fix the punctuation, and I have noticed [the revision page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/49067/revisions) shows a change that is not the real one.

[image: screenshot]

Watching it, it seems I changed the text from "requires the rules modulethough" to "requires the Rules module, though" when I changed it from "requires the rules module though."

The difference shown for the Markdown source is more correct than the difference shown for the rendered output, even though it shows I deleted *module* to add *modules,* when I just added a comma after *module*.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I noticed such edits lately and wondered about that; didn't bother to check deeper though so well done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled over this bug report; I fixed this issue a few months later. See [Diff removes a space when it shouldn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166923/diff-removes-a-space-when-it-shouldnt) for a detailed explanation of the issue and the fix.