# Tag shows as deleted and re-inserted, even though I didn't edit it

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, diff

I [added the "osx" tag](https://superuser.com/posts/553922/revisions) to a question. Nothing else.

[image]

It shows that the "colors" tag was removed, and then re-added. What gives? Wouldn't it make sense to show it like this?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed weird stuff like this too.  Saying I've messed with stuff I didn't touch.

Comment: Looks like the diff algo is a bit greedy. Not sure there is much we can do about it.

Comment: @Oded Well, if it's not worth the effort completely rewriting the diff algorithm, so be it :)

Comment: Ah, unintended side effect of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167490/115866).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an unintended consequence of [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166923/diff-removes-a-space-when-it-shouldnt/167490#167490), where the "prepend a space" cheat (that's the "Jeff" case near the bottom of that post) was too eager. Fixed in the next build.