# Incorrect side-by-side visual diff when adding ` characters to links

Tags: bug, diff

In https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/345508/revisions, a user edited my post to, among other things, have ` characters. The side-by-side Markdown diff shows that `[the zsh manual][1]` was changed to have ` characters around "zsh", but the visual side-by-side diff shows that "manual" was changed in addition to "zsh".

Comment: It's a bit difficult to highlight a character that doesn't exist... would you prefer that nothing was highlighted in the visual?

Comment: This is fixed now, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291341/115866.