# Revision history marks spaces when retagging occurs

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, revisions-list, diff

When question tags have been changed you can see spaces marked with green or red color. E.g. [rev 18](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/revisions?page=4):

> [image: retag]

I suppose it's done because of easily implementation, but it looks ugly.

Is it possible do not mark spaces when retagging occurs?

iOS app shows it much better:

> [image: ios-app]

Comment: I'm not seeing this [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/239/revisions) or on other sites I frequent. Is this perhaps a bug that's specific to one site's design? Which site did you screenshot this on?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie link to revision is provided in the post body. On MSE you can see same effect [here on rev.20](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions?page=8).

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Odd that it only shows up between some tag changes and not all of them.

Comment: Possibly related to [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291341/339911).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you [suspected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292576/revision-history-marks-spaces-when-retagging-occurs#comment950702_292576) correctly, this was caused by [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256174/improve-display-of-suggested-edit-deltas-for-format-changes/291341#291341), which (among other things) made handling of spaces in diffs more consistent, which in case of tag diffs (which are just implemented as HTML diffs of the rendered tags) wasn't really what we wanted. Fixed in the next build

Comment: [Oh the irony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A78Gs.png).